# Standardizing Slightly Different Values Across 4 Dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, selenium-chromedriver, fuzzywuzzy, difflib

I am looking for an elegant (computationally less expensive solution) to this:

I have 4 scraped dataframes containing football club names. Sometimes 1 or 2 out of 4 frames contain the name slightly differently:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Home Team': ['France', 'Italy, 'Spain', 'Palmeiras SE']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Home Team': ['France Woman', 'Italy, 'Spain', 'Palmeiras']})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Home Team': ['France', 'Italy, 'Spain Woman', 'Palmeiras SE']})

df4 = pd.DataFrame({'Home Team': ['France', 'Italy, 'Spain Woman', 'Palmeiras']})
```

In reality, all dataframes have around 50 to a 100 values and they are updated daily. I have tried fuzzywuzzy and difflib libraries and even thought about bringing in master data as a point of reference for all future updates. All of these require a high number of computation and someone might have a better idea.

Appreciate it.
Kristof

A couple of things that somewhat worked for me:

Fuzzymatcher with 2 frames:

```
import fuzzymatcher

result = fuzzymatcher.fuzzy_left_join(whoscored, olbg_data, 'Home Team', 'Home Team')

output = result[['Home Team_left', 'Predicted Result_left', 'Predicted Result_right']]

output.columns = ['Home Team', 'Predicted Result (Whoscored)', 'Predicted Result (OLBG Data)']
```

This easily picked up things like:

Talleres    Talleres    CA Talleres de Cordoba
Germany     Germany     Germany Women

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd2Qp.png)

When I use 4 frames:

```
import fuzzymatcher

result = fuzzymatcher.fuzzy_left_join(whoscored, olbg_data, 'Home Team', 'Home Team')
output = result[['Home Team_left', 'Predicted Result_left', 'Predicted Result_right']]
output.columns = ['Home Team', 'Predicted Result (Whoscored)', 'Predicted Result (OLBG Data)']

result_predictz = fuzzymatcher.fuzzy_left_join(whoscored, predictz_output, 'Home Team', 'Home Team')
output = output.copy()
output.loc[:, 'Predicted Result (Predictz)'] = result_predictz['Predicted Result_right']

result_vitibet = fuzzymatcher.fuzzy_left_join(whoscored, vitibet, 'Home Team', 'Home Team')
output = output.copy()
output.loc[:, 'Predicted Result (Vitibet)'] = result_vitibet['Predicted Result_right']
```

It gives a somewhat ok result but some values come back as NaN even though they are in the dataframe. Dataframe itself: [Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lM14G.png)

As you can see, Vitibet['Predicted Result'] will have row 7 back as NaN, even though it is present just with a slightly different value: [Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgCuL.png)

Comment: You must define the logic of the standardization. E.g. when there is more than one word, take the first one only

Comment: Hi EscadeSupremo! Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be helpful, as gtomer said, if you could include your logic. Also, including code examples of what you have right now would go a long way (and also help benchmark any solutions people might create)

Comment: also, if the real trickiness of the problem comes with 300+ entries, and 3+ dataframes, I would potentially look at either including that scale of data in your question, or creating code which programmatically creates sample data of a similar scale

Comment: Thanks guys, I answered with my closest success so far.

Comment: thanks for that! Can you answer gtomer's question now

Comment: @gtomer I thought about the best way to pre-process the data but not sure what would be a good general rule here. Taking the first full string would yield some very different results. Case in point: Talleres -> CA Talleres de Cordoba and Cruzeiro Esporte Clube -> Cruzeiro